# Почему OpenVPN как будто бы не работает на Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Имею файл конфигурции для openvpn file.ovpn

На Windows все работает отлично.

На Ubuntu тоже установил `sudo apt install openvpn`, положил в его папку файл конфига.

Вроде бы все работает как надо. IP показывает впн сервера, **НО** на залоченые РКНом сайты не заходит. Пишет что ресурс заблокирован и т.п. (как будто я захожу без ВПН).

В чем может быть дело?

Вот конфигурационная часть файла:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote 11.22.33.44 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

- запустите сервис

  ```
  sudo systemctl start openvpn@file
  ```

  где `file` название вашего файала конфигурации
- убедитесь что сервис запущен

  ```
  sudo systemctl status openvpn@file
  ```

  или так

  ```
  ip addr show tun0
  ```
- если не запустился, нужно смотреть логи что ему мешает